# iMovie 09, setting all clips to 'fit' mode

Tags: imovie

I'm currently making an experiment that requires taking loads of pictures and then putting them into a video for analysis. However when I import them to iMovie 09, it gives the Ken Burns effect, which I don't like. I have to have the pictures in the 'fit' mode when cropping. I can change this feature manually for each picture but this takes a lot of time.

Is there a way in which I can set all the images to have the 'fit' mode? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use iMovie version 10 but it this feature should be compatible. Drag them all to the Timeline. Press CTL+A to select them all or shift+select to select the ones you want. Then click on the crop button Press fit that's it

Answer (score 0):

In iMovie 10, @soulshined 's answer doesn't work for all clips if you've already dragged your clips into the timeline. It would be onerous to remove all clips from the timeline and then re-add them again if the clips already have other edits applied that you don't want to manually re-apply. To apply the crop mode *in-place* to all clips you already have on the timeline, do the following:

- Crop (or adjust) just *one* clip to the desired final alteration
- Select that clip, and then click on the Edit menu, then click "Copy".
- Press Cmd+A to select all other clips, or shift+select just the ones you want
- Click on the Edit menu, then go to "Paste Adjustments", then click "All" (or click "Crop", if you only want to apply the crop adjustment).

Note this doesn't work with normal copy/paste, you have to either use the "Paste Adjustments" menu or a special paste command (which happens to be Cmd+Alt+V on my computer, but may be different on yours)